# Scraping a tables from websites

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-scraping

Im looking to scrape some tables from external sources and include them on mine

how can this be achieved i have managed to use the below code to scrap images how can i modify it to scrape all tables and output the table on the page

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.imdb.com/');
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table'); 
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo $image->getAttribute('tr');
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: i have tried editing the above code to table instead of image however it doesnt work

Comment: Replace your code above with the code you've tried and we can determine what is going wrong. For starters, a table won't have a src attribute, but because you didn't post your example, I don't know if you already took it out.

Comment: have updated the code

Comment: tr is an element and not an attribute so that won't work very well. See if this gets you anywhere: `$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table'); 
foreach($tables as $table) {
    var_dump($table);
}`

Comment: that just outputs the contents of the table on the page doesnt dispaly the table

Comment: object(DOMElement)#6 (17) { ["tagName"]=> string(5) "table" ["schemaTypeInfo"]=> NULL ["nodeName"]=> string(5 - it outputs alot of this code

Comment: are you allowed to re-embded IMDB tables on your site, without advertising?

Comment: You might want to use something like: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/ Then you can run `$url = 'http://www.imdb.com/';
$dom = str_get_html(file_get_contents($url));

foreach($html->find('table') as $table) {
   // your code here
echo $table;
}` Otherwise, you're going to have to parse up the result up above and spit it back out the way you want it.

Comment: the imdb site was just a site to test it on i dont plan on scraping this site

Comment: mkaatman is there any other way without 3rd party scripts